# Ionic 3 Cordova onclick event

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i need to single and long press on same button or label on ionic. i have done single and long click individually but could`nt achieve both on same label.

here is my code

html.

```
    <ion-col class = "mystyle"   (click) ="wajid()" >
 <ion-label id = "aa"   > اَبَدًا </ion-label>
```

```
<ion-col class = "mystyle" (press) ="wajid()"   >
 <ion-label id = "aa"   > اَبَدًا </ion-label>
```

kindly help me with this. thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using (tap) and (press) events to trigger short/single click and long press.

```
<ion-col class="mystyle" (press)="itemPressed()" (tap)="itemTapped()">
   <ion-label id="aa"> اَبَدًا </ion-label>  
</ion-col>
```

Comment: suzan i need specific functionality on single and long press as when i long press it fries single click functionality also with long press i need when i long press it detects that its not single click so do not execute single click code just execute long press

Comment: Try the above example. It executes `itemPressed()` on single click and `itemTapped()` if long press is detected.

Comment: i need both events on same button and both events have different audios to play now the thing is how to detect whether single press audio to play or long audio to play in typescript or javascript ?

Comment: you can play the audio for single press in (tap) event and play audio for long press in (press) event

Comment: how can i implement different functionality for the same button but different events (long and tap). when user tap it should do something and when user press it shoud do something. how to differentiate the long and tap javascript ?

Comment: As you can see in the example i have given. functions assigned for (press) executes when log press the component and (tab) executes when single click is detected.

Comment: i used but for next button i ll have to add 2 more functions for that ?

Comment: if you want to play another music, you surely have to add that functions. or just send parameters to the functions and play music according to that